# docker-compose down wait for container X finish before stop container Y

Tags: docker, mariadb, jetty

I have to deploy a web app with a Jetty Server. This app need a database, running on MariaDB. Here the `docker-compose` file used to deploy the app:

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:

  jetty:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/jetty/Dockerfile
    container_name: app-jetty
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      mariadb:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - app
    links:
      - "mariadb:mariadb"

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.7
    container_name: app-mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myPassword
      MARIADB_DATABASE: APPDB
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mariadb-admin", "--protocol", "tcp", "ping", "-u root", "-pmyPassword" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3m
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  datavolume:
```

I use a `volume` to keep the data of mariaDB even if I use `docker-compose down`. On my Jetty app, the data is store into the database when the `contextDestroyed` function is load (when the container is stopped).

But I have an another problem: when I execute `docker-compose down`, all the containers are stopped and deleted. Although the mariaDB is the last stopped container (that's what the terminal is saying), the save on the `contexDestroyed` is "interrupt" and I lost some informations because mariaDB container is stopped when the Jetty container still saving data. I tested to stop every container but the mariaDB and my data is succefully saved without loss, so the problem is obviously the mariaDB container.

How can I indicate to the `mariadb` container to wait for all containers for stopping before stop itself?

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you in any way? If so - please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `depends_on` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) - your dependency will force the following order of shutdown:

1. `web`
2. `mariadb`

You might want to look into what's happening during the shutdown of these containers and add some custom logic that will guarantee your data is consistent.

You can influence what happens during the shutdown of a container in 2 main ways:

1. adding a custom script as an entrypoint
2. handling the `SIGTERM` signal yourself

here's the relevant [documentation on this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/).

Maybe the simplest - not necessarily the smartest - way would be to add a `sleep(5)` to the db shutdown, so your app has enough time to flush its writes.